# What is dataset Bounding Box?

Tags: dataset, geospatial, gdal, r-raster, imaging

I am bit new to Imaging and want to understand below:

1. what is the bounding box of a dataset and why is that needed? Does it represent something of measurement in real world or just for computer screen where it is displayed? How is this related to the image size specified in pixels?
2. What does WMTS layers zoom level & matrix sets mean? I understand that WMTS works by using getting tiles of the dataset. Also, I see that the get Capabilities for a specific WMTS dataset returns back matrix Sets in the XML which I don't understand?
3. what do the matrix datasets and zoom levels signify and how can I understand them as a layman?

I have tried googling a bit but it looks like the articles assume some technical knowledge around this already which I am trying to gather.

Answer (score 0):

1. A bounding box is the (imaginary) rectangle that you can draw around a dataset (or feature) that touches it's maximums and minimums in both X and Y direction. It is measured in the same units as the geometry. It is related to the image size in pixels as the resolution or scale which are bbox.width/image.width or (the inverse), and are in units of metres/pixel or pixels/metre (or degree or foot).

[image]

2. A WMTS layer is a set of pre-rendered tiles that have been produced at a fixed set of scales and over a fixed area. These are related in the matrix sets of a WMTS layer - the zoom level is how far down that set of scales you have traversed with 0 being the top and an arbitrary number (usually between 15-20 for global data sets) being the lowest (or most detailed).
3. See 2. - You should not really need to understand them in detail as your client library will handle all of that for you.